# facebook facepile shows my friends only

Tags: facebook, facepile

I would like to show all people which use my app. I tried this facepile code but it shows my friends only.

```
<iframe id="fbusage" scrolling="no" allowTransparency="true" src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/facepile.php?app_id=123&amp;amp;width=750&amp;amp;max_rows=1" style="border:none; overflow:hidden; width:750px; height: 60px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```

How can I show all people using my app in iframe?

Comment: hi Matthew, when I log out facepile disappears (is not visible on my site). It looks like facepile is for showing my friends only, isn't it? maybe I should use another social plugin.. but which one - when I need to show faces of people which use my fb app? thankx

Comment: „It looks like facepile is for showing my friends only, isn't it?” – to me it also looks like the documentation clearly states that, saying „The plugin only displays friends photos. If the user does not have friends who have liked your page or have connected to your site, no faces will be shown.” https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/facepile/

Comment: thanks CBroe, now I understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, there might be a reason for this plugin only showing friends, and that reason might be called *privacy* …?

If you don’t care and want to do it anyway – in that case, please have a *thorough* look trough the platform policies first, if that’s even allowed – you can generate such a list yourself. Just read out the stored user ids from your app’s database or whatever, select some of them by whatever means you think are best, and then put out some HTML code that displays their name and picture. (Picture can be displayed via graph.facebook.com/*userid*/picture, and if you don’t have user names already stored in your database, you’ll have to make a request to the Graph API with the ids first.)

Comment: wow, so there isn't fb plugin for this? So I should do it by myself (make fql request or read users from my db)... I thought there is simple solution for this. :/